Loop through a comma-separated shell variable, n items at a time
I have a comma-separated bash variable like
FOO=ab,cd,ef,gh,ij

and I want to iterate over every item, n at a time like
n=2
for i in {get every n $FOO items}; do
  echo i
done

and get the result:
ab,cd
ef,gh
ij

How would I go about this? Note, my question is similar to Loop through a comma-separated shell variable, except for the step of n in each iteration, which I am not sure how to apply to the answer there.

will probably be easier to process if FOO is an array, or the contents of FOO are converted to an array (eg, IFS=',' read -r -a FOOarr <<< "${FOO}"); once you've got an array this answer (from the 'duplicate' link) appears to do what you want

Without an array: echo "${foo//,/$'\n'}" | paste -d, - -

Either turn FOO into an array and then use a counting loop to traverse the array (with step size n), or use a while-loop and inside the loop a regexp, which splits the variable into two parts, one containing the first n fields, and the other parts containing the rest.

echo AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ | xargs -d, -n2 echo | tr ' ' ,
